# Parse with Swift - If Contains Channel

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse for push notifications with Swift.  I'm trying to write an if statement that searches the currently subscribed channels and sees if they have subscribed to that specific channel.

Here's my code:

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
if(contains(currentInstallation.channels as String, "game1")) {
   // do something 
}
```

I get the following error:

> Could not find an overload for 'contains' that accepts the supplied arguments

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast `[AnyObject]` to `String`. Try this (if you're using Swift 1.2):

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
if (contains(currentInstallation.channels as! [String], "game1")) {
    // do something
}
```